# Rewrite link working in locahost, but it not working on IP address (MVC web in iis7)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a website (using ASP.NET MVC5) on IIS7 at my server, this website use rewrite link

I can run it with localhost address normal, but when I run it by IP address, link is not working

Link localhost (normal) : http://localhost:2019/tin-tuc-su-kien.html

Link ip (error): http://27.72.31.185:2019/tin-tuc-su-kien.html

Homepage: http://27.72.31.185:2019

Please, I need your help... Thanks

Comment: Can you disclose where is the html page in you site directory structure and also is it copied into folder that IIS use?

Comment: Learn how to check it out on your own, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: could you please provide folder structure and binding detail?